# pdflatex/lualatex called from shutdown script can not find installed packages

Tags: pdftex, luatex, ubuntu, linux, bash

At work I have set up a little backup script on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 machine. The script backs up my machine to an external hard drive. After this is done it copies a LaTeX project to my Dropbox and compiles it. This project is some kind of a logbook of my work.

I know this is a rather unconventional use case and I could just copy the source or push it to a git repo but first of all git would be a bit of an overkill and second of all there were already two instances where I was glad for having it in pdf form on my mobile when I had to start up a tty shell because gnome wouldn't start up.

The problem now is that for some reason both pdflatex and lualatex tell me that they can't find the `.sty` files. The backup script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# .... some system backup code ....

## sync linux setup document to Dropbox
# remove .pdf in order to guarantee that project is compiled
rm /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/logBook.pdf
# compile project in origin 
make -C /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/ >> /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/makeLog
# copy files to destination
cp -rp /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/ /home/wright/Dropbox
```

And my `Makefile` contains the following lines:

```
SHELL=bash
TARGET=linuxSetup.pdf
FLAGS= --shell-escape
SRC= ./*.tex ./header/*.tex  ./chapters/*.tex ./references/*.bib ./titlepage/*.tex 
TIKZ= ./tikz/*.tex
LL= pdflatex


all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET:%.pdf=%.tex) $(SRC) $(TIKZ)
    @$(LL) $(FLAGS) $<
#   makeglossaries $(TARGET:%.pdf=%"")
#   makeindex -s headingsStyle.ist $(TARGET:%.pdf=%.idx)
#   bibtex $(TARGET:%.pdf=%"")
    @$(LL) $(FLAGS) $<
    @$(LL) $(FLAGS) $<
```

The backup script is placed in `/etc/init.d/backup` and contains a symbolic link to `/etc/rc0.d/S01Backup`.

The scripts are simple enough, yet they still won't find the `.sty` files. I tried excluding the `.sty` files to find out if the problem was caused by specific ones but regardless of how many I exclude there are always more that the compiler won't find. I switched the compiler yet that does not seem to be the issue either. And also I executed the complete backup script via `sudo` or as the root user, both of which worked perfectly fine without any errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a very well phrased question, but I wonder if this wouldn't be better suited for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Unix.SX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, I thought about that as well, might post it there too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was still residue from my previous texlive installation that I made via apt repositories. There were texlive directories in `/usr/share/texlive/` (from repositories) and `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex` (user installed). The shutdown script apparently called the wrong compiler, which was the one `/usr/share`. When I uninstalled the repositories via `apt-get purge`, rather than `apt-get remove` this folder was deleted and everything worked perfectly fine with the installation in `/usr/local`.